# Qt 5.12.2 version with msvc 2017 application doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, windows-7

I have a qt kit with Qt version 5.12.2 and compiler version visual studio 2019 ie 16.3 (msvc 2017 for qt). My problem is 32/64 bit regardless of the architecture of the computer. Because I am working on 32bit. Under these conditions, my qt application that I compile and link does not open because of i get **api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing** error in professional while working in Windows 7 enterprise.

What setting do I need to work in windows 7? Can a qmake.exe be set as static according to the compiler without changing the qt version?

Comment: ***Can a qmake.exe be set as static according to the compiler without changing the qt version?*** Most likely no. If you are using Qt that was provided by the online installer you don't have static Qt or static runtime (these are 2 independent things). With that said if you did recompile the Qt framework yourself I am not sure that making either or both static is the solution to your problem. You may want to start with a simple hello world type application and get that to work first before trying your more complicated application.

Comment: What does "... does not open ..." mean? Can you edit the question and post any error messages you receive?

Comment: @SebDieBln thanks i updated it.

Comment: @drescherjm I want to compile msvc 2013 with qt 5.12 but 2015 and 2017 versions available in installer. is there any solution for this?

Comment: ***does not open because of i get api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing*** Maybe you need to install the Visual Studio 32 bit redistributable. `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` I don't believe that file actually exists however it is handled by the redistributable.

Comment: You can download the source code for Qt and build it yourself with your compiler. With that said I am not sure if Qt5 compiles with msvc2013. I don't remember. I have compiled Qt hundreds of times between work and home. You do need to install Perl, Python and possibly ruby.

Comment: If this official Qt documentation is correct no msvc-2013 is too old: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#building-from-source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#building-from-source)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either install Visual C++ Redistributable runtime, or provide its dll files alongside with your application.

These DLL files are in the following folders. You can just copy them to the folder with your main binary executable:

1. Universal CRT (`api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` is a part of it): `C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Redist/ucrt/DLLs/x86` and `C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Redist/ucrt/DLLs/x64`.
2. Visual C++ 2019 runtime (2017 runtime paths are slightly different but they are similar to 2019, and they also are binary compatible, so you can just use VC2019 runtime for apps built using VC2017):
   `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Redist/MSVC/14.29.30133/x86/Microsoft.VC142.CRT` and `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Redist/MSVC/14.29.30133/x64/Microsoft.VC142.CRT`.